# как скопировать все содержимое в определённой папке

Tags: python

Мне нужно с папки C:\Users\romaz\Downloads\Telegram Desktop скопировать все содержимое в другую папку например C:\Users\romaz\Desktop\Telegram Desktop через shutil.copy2

Comment: shutil.copytree

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import shutil
        
shutil.copy2('C:\Users\romaz\Downloads\Telegram Desktop' , 'C:\Users\romaz\Desktop\Telegram Desktop')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ошибка `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

Comment: не работает это, выдаёт ошибку